# py.test and teardown

Tags: pytest

I'm developing a test suite in py.test which connects to a networked hardware device and changes settings etc. Each test method would change some combination of settings and then assert the result. How can I have test-specific teardown, without having to reset ALL the device settings after every test?

Comment: See [fixture finalization / executing teardown code](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code) and [classic xunit-style setup](http://pytest.org/latest/xunit_setup.html) of the documentation. Now, as I tested the fin function it did not work.

Comment: I guess mocking the device connection is not an option for you, although I personally think this would be the best option. Actually doing the changes on a test device would be more of an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe memorize the "previous" setup settings and then only do the neccessary settings in the next setup (by comparing "memory" versus "wanted" settings)?